# Elementary linear algebra question. Dimension of linear subvariety. Exercise 2.14 Fulton's 'Algebraic Curves'

Tags: linear-algebra

A linear subvariety of $k^n$, $k$ a field, is the vanishing set of first degree polynomials $F_i$ in $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ over $k$, $V(F_1, \ldots, F_r)$.
Suppose $T_j, j =1, \ldots, n$ is a polynomial of degree 1 in $X_1, \ldots ,X_n$ over $k$, $$T_j=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{ij}X_i +a_{0j}$$ and 
let $T$ be the map sending $(x_1, \ldots , x_n) \in k^n$ to $(T_1(x_1, \ldots , x_n), \ldots, T_n(x_1, \ldots , x_n)) \in k^n $. $T$ is called an affine change of coordinates of $k^n$, iff $T$ is invertible, i.e. iff the square matrix $(a_{ij}), i,j= 1, \ldots, n$ is invertible. The inverse of an affine change of coordinates and compostion of affine changes of coordinates is again an affine change of coordinates.

One can show that an appropriate affine change of coordinates transforms a linear subvariety into $V(X_{m+1}, \ldots , X_n)$, with $m<n$. Show that $m$ is uniquely defined.

Hint by Fulton: "Suppose there were an affine change of coordinates such that $V(X_{m+1}, \ldots , X_n)^T= V(X_{s+1}, \ldots , X_n)$, $m<s$, show that $T_{m+1}, \ldots, T_n$ are dependent." Following the answers below, I think this is a typo and $m$ and $s$ should be switched around (or altenatively  "Suppose there were an affine change of coordinates such that $V(X_{s+1}, \ldots , X_n)^T= V(X_{m+1}, \ldots , X_n)$, $m<s$, show that $T_{m+1}, \ldots, T_n$ are dependent.")

So, let's assume that $V(X_{m+1}, \ldots , X_n)^T= V(X_{s+1}, \ldots , X_n), m>s$

The image of $V(X_{m+1}, \ldots , X_n)= \left \{ (x_1, \ldots , x_m,0,\ldots,0) \mid x_1, \ldots, x_m \in k \right \}$ under $T$ is exactly $V(X_{s+1}, \ldots , X_n)= \left \{ (x_1, \ldots , x_s,0,\ldots,0) \mid x_1, \ldots, x_s \in k \right \}$. Inserting $(0,\ldots, 0)$, $(1, 0,\ldots, 0)$, $(0,1, \ldots, 0)$ etc. gives $a_{ij}= 0$ for $0\le i\le m$ and $s+1\le j\le n$. That's the only thing I have got.

Comment: What do you mean by "singular"? Your matrix isn't square. It seems to be $(n+1) \times n$, since you have the constant terms $a_{0j}$.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that it would be obvious what was meant. I edited it (but not sure how to do this in an elegant way). Essentially, you want to show that $T$ as defined above is not invertible.

Comment: What do you mean by "the image of $(x_1, \ldots , x_m,0,\ldots,0)$ under $T$ is exactly $(y_1, \ldots , y_s,0,\ldots,0)$"? That the image of the set of all vectors of the form $(x_1, \ldots , x_m,0,\ldots,0)$ under $T$ is exactly the set of all vectors of the form $(y_1, \ldots , y_s,0,\ldots,0)$?

Comment: Thank you, Darij. I messed up, arghhhh. I've edited. By the way, this is problem 2.14 in Fulton's 'algebraic curves'.

Comment: Since $V^T$ is defined as $T^-1[V]$, by the question in fact we have $T[V(X_{s+1}, \ldots , X_n)] = V(X_{m+1}, \ldots , X_n)$, so it seems to me that the book has no error in putting $m<s$.

Comment: I would appreciate an answer to the question of the existence of an appropriate affine change of coordinates  transforming a linear subvariety into $V(X_{m+1}, \ldots ,X_n)$, with $m<n$..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You noted that $a_{ij}= \ldots = a_{mj}= 0$ for $0\le i\le m$ and $s+1\le j\le n$. Then for these $j$,
$T_j=\sum_{i=m+1}^{n} a_{ij}X_i.$. We can interpret these $T_j$ as $n-s$ vectors in a vector space $k^{n-m}$. By since $m<s$ we have $n-s<n-m$, so such vectors can be linearly independent (but we should have a problem in the case $m>s$). For instance, let $n=3$, $s=2$, and $m=1$. Put $T_1=X_1$, $T_2=X_2$, and $T_3=X_3$. Then $T(x_1,0,0)=(x_1,0,0)$, so the question condition is satisfied, but the polynomials $T_1$, $T_2$, and $T_3$ are linearly independent over $k$.

Comment: Hi, in your 'counterexample', $m=s=1$

Comment: But you might have solved it, because $m$ and $s$ are interchangeable, I'll have a think about it.

Comment: @RomandadeGore If the image of $V(X_{m+1}, \ldots , X_n)$ under $T$ is exactly $V(X_{s+1}, \ldots , X_n)$ and $m<s$ then it looks strange, because an affine map $T$ should not increase dimension of an affine variety.

Comment: You are right. Probably a typo in the hint to the exercise in Fulton's book. I have further edited my question and accepted your answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the map $T-(a_{01},...,a_{0n})=A^{T}$ where $A=(a_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$, the square matrix. If $T(x_{1},...,x_{m},0...,0)=T(y_{1},...,y_{s},0,...,0)$ then $A^T(x_{1},...,x_{m},0,...,0)=A^T(y_{1},...,y_{s},0...,0)$. In particular $(y_{1}-x_{1},...,y_{m}-x_{m},y_{m+1},...,y_{s},0,...,0)\neq0$ lies in the kernel of $A^T$, hence $A$ is not invertible and therefore is singular.

Comment: True, but here we just have $T(x_1, \ldots , x_m, 0, \ldots, 0)=(y_1, \ldots , y_s, 0, \ldots, 0)$